# Making a div expand with jQuery without moving divs floating to it

Tags: jquery, css-float

I'm trying to get an effect similar to what you can find at http://www.nokiausa.com/us-en/products/ with a grid of basic information, where a click expands information over a neighbouring item.

One problem I'm having is that expanding my div is making the neighbouring div move - I think I might have to use the clone function to produce a child with absolute positioning but I'm not sure how I would actually do that.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.color.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function growRight(){
        $('#stuff1').animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FF8600"
        }, 750 );
        $('#stuff1').animate({
            width: "510px"
        }, 750, function() {});
    }

</script>
<style>
    ul{
    display:block;
    width:520px;
    background-color:#888888;
    }

    li{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#B8B8B8;
    margin:5px;
    }

    p{
    display:block;
    }

    div.contentright{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:250px;
    width:260px;
    height:250px;
    }

    .clearLeft{
    clear:left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="gridbox">
    <li class="stuff" id="stuff1">
        <a href="javascript:growRight()">Stuff 1</a>
        <div class="contentright">
            This is a load of content. Content content content.
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Stuff 2
    </li>
    <li>
        Stuff 3
    </li>
    <li>
        Stuff 4
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I would create a jsfiddle so its easier to see your problem. You could have css or js that we can't see so if you can replicate it on jsfiddle then we can have a sandboxed problem to solve.

Comment: Not immediately helpful, but all their code is available to see how they did it. ;-) For example, each row of 4 is actually subdivided into 2 (to accomodate the direction the expanding div needs to go). As far as I can tell from quick inspection, they're using floats.

Comment: @Robotsushi, this is all the code I have right now - the only code not listed is the jQuery library and the color plugin for that to allow color animation. I jsut copied it to a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zUbTQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution which pretty much follows the approach I mentioned in the question - this clones the cell, which in turn animates. CSS properties ensure "expandinatorright" sits absolutely on top of its parent (of course, with z-index making sure it is rendered above everything else).

```
    function growRight(){
        $('.stuff')
            .clone(false)
            .addClass('expandinatorright')
            .appendTo($('.stuff'));
        $('.expandinatorright').animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FF8600"
        }, 750 );
        $('.expandinatorright').animate({
            width: "510px"
        }, 750, function() {});
    }
```

I hope this is useful for anyone who might run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this calls for some clever usage of `position:absolute`. `z-index` only sets the order for elements that would appear on top of each other in the first place.

Comment: I was thinking this, but this would probably require the div to be cloned by jQuery, with this clone then given the absolute position. I honestly have no idea how I would do this.

Comment: `element.clone().appendTo(target)` should get you started (:

Comment: Thanks man, I've got it now with your help. I'll post the solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were meaning?

Please excuse the horrendous formatting, I wrote it quickly

http://jsfiddle.net/y3QBw/5/

```
var li_original_height = $('#stuff1').css('z-index');

function growRight() {
    var $stuff = $('#stuff1'),
        li_left = $stuff.offset().left,
        li_top = $stuff.offset().top,
        li_stuff_width = $stuff.outerWidth(true) + 5,
        $sibling = $stuff.next();

    $sibling.css('margin-left', li_stuff_width);
    $stuff
        .css({
            'z-index': 1000,
            background: '#588EC8',
            position: 'fixed',
            top: li_top,
            left: li_left,
            margin: 0
        })
        .animate({
            width: "510px"
        }, 750, function() {});
}

function hideRight() {
    var $stuff = $('#stuff1'),
        $sibling = $stuff.next();

        $stuff.animate({
            width: "250px"
        }, 750, function() {
            $stuff.css({
                'z-index': li_original_height,
                background: '#B8B8B8',
                position: 'relative',
                top: 'auto',
                left: 'auto',
                margin: 5
           });
            $sibling.css('margin-left', 5);
        });

}

$('#stuff1 a').toggle(
    function () {
        growRight(); 
        return false;
    },
    function () {
        hideRight(); 
        return false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a quick stab at this, I would suggest that before animating, add a `z-index` property to the element that you wish to enlarge. This should make it go above the neighboring element and hide it instead of pushing it down.

Something like:

```
function growRight(){
        $("#stuff1").css("z-index","5");
        $('#stuff1').animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FF8600"
        }, 750 );
        $('#stuff1').animate({
            width: "510px"
        }, 750, function() {});
    }
```

Comment: I wish it were this simple, but as the other guy said, I don't think z-index works like that. Even if it did, it would still mess up the layout by letting the divs slide back...