# JQuery Accordion - Expand above the button

Tags: jquery, dialog, accordion, expand

In the past I asked about how to open and close accordions when the user wants to have each one open and close. This is the example that solved the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaWaheed/JhndX/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<!--* Created using jsbin.com by roXon 29/10/2012
* Source can be edited via http://jsbin.com/uleloy/2/edit
* -->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style id="jsbin-css">
        *{margin:0;padding:0;}
    .accordion h3{ background:#eee; padding:10px; }
    .accordion div{ background:#999;   }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <div>Content 1...</div>
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <div>Content 2...</div>  
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
    <div>Content 3...</div>  
    <h3>Title 4</h3>
    <div>Content 4...</div>  
</div>

<script>
    var $accordionIO = $('.accordion h3');
    $accordionIO.next('div').hide();

    $accordionIO.click(function(){
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

I'm now wondering, will it be possible to have the section that expands, expands above the button in an upwards direction, rather than the normal, which opens underneath the button and expands vertically down?

Comment: have you tried putting the divs above the <h3> links, and changing the jquery 'next' to 'prev'

Comment: Hey, that works perfectly! The only problem is it pushes the buttons down. Is there a way of making the expanded area only open upwards, leaving the button static at one place? Thanks.

Comment: It will push the buttons down, because you're adding dynamic content (the div) above each button. I'm not sure what you mean 'only open upwards'...

Comment: If you imagine taking a credit card or cash/note out of your wallet while holding the wallet in vertical position, I want to be able to achieve an effect like that. I've just found this jQuery code, which almost resembles what I'd like to accomplish but with the whole panel opening up. Apologies, the accordion wasn't a good example to use.

Comment: I think I get what you mean. Instead of the buttons being stacked on top of one another, you want a space between them to allow the div to expand into it?

Comment: That's beyond my measly js skills unfortunately!  I did a quick search & found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219486/making-a-div-expand-with-jquery-without-moving-divs-floating-to-it) which could be a solution for you.

Comment: Wow that's really close to what I need. I'll have a look into it and will let you know how it goes. Thanks again.