# floats to left or right when clicked on play button

Tags: jquery, html, css

for better explaination please have a look at [this page](http://kemitraanpendidikan.or.id/?page_id=618) then click on audio tab.

when i click on play link (eg. Indahnya dunia – merayakan Hari Hewan Dunia ) the mp3 player, then i click on another play link (eg. Berita dari penghargaan Australia) causing the player move to the right, messed up. what is wrong with the css? i really have no idea of what is going on.

almost similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219486/making-a-div-expand-with-jquery-without-moving-divs-floating-to-it)

Comment: I don't see any issue with the site. Please post code and more of an explanation such as the browser you are using, whether you have cross-browser tested it, and what you expect it to do. Don't expect us to trawl through your code to find the issue.

Comment: I have checked with Chrome, however I dont see anything that should be out of the blue.

Comment: Used Firefox and I don't see a problem. Can you tell us which browser and operating system you are using?

Comment: i use both firefox and chrome with ubuntu OS

Comment: another case, click Indahnya dunia – merayakan Hari Hewan Dunia first then Terima kasih kepada semua penyiar radio

Comment: @DarielPratama have you fixed  the issue ?

Comment: @bboymaanu yep, fixed..i follow your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @DarielPratama Ok, I will let you know if I find any alternative solution in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `min-height` for the `.podcast-wrap .podcasts-item`

```
.podcast-wrap .podcasts-item{
   min-height: 57px;
   ----------
   ----------
}
```

**Updated answer**

You try suppurate multi `div`
CSS

```
ul.audio-section{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;

    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.podcasts-item{
    float: left;
    width: 97%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #999;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="audio-section">
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
</ul>
<ul class="audio-section">
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
    <li class="podcasts-item">lorem</li>
</ul>
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/8MJfQ/

Comment: it works, but is there another way instead of adding min-height? because i want it to be dynamically change the height, just like fold and expand.

Comment: @DarielPratama please have a look alternative solution